# How to set object value using hidden form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an users model ( cliens and perfomers) and also cliens has an order. Perfomers could accepts this orders and i need to put accept button in show template of order. I'm using hidden form in show template

```
<%= form_tag @order, :method => 'get' do %>
<%=hidden_field_tag :order_perfomer_id, current_user.id%>

<%= submit_tag "Accept order"%>
```

It doesn't work. Is it wrong way?  In console i see

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_perfomer_id"=>"3", "commit"=>"Accept order", "id"=>"1"}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What about this doesn't work?  Though you can use `form_for` as suggested the hidden field is passed with a value of 3 in your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use  [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) insted of form_tag

```
<%= form_for @order, :method => 'get' do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :order_perfomer_id, value: current_user.id%>

<%= f.submit "Accept order"%>
```

Comment: `f.hidden_field_tag` should be `f.hidden_field`.

Comment: Idk why, but it still doesnt work.  Order_perfomer _id doesnt change.

Comment: @Pavan should i write something to controller also?

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev show your controller. Have you edited strong parameters section to something like:

`params.require(:order).permit(:order_perfomer_id)`

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :order_perfomer_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Rails 3 and 2:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :order_perfomer_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Also, you need to use [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) instead of [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) and your form becomes this:

```
<%= form_for @order, :method => 'get' do |f|%>
<%= f.hidden_field :order_perfomer_id, value: current_user.id%>

<%= f.submit "Accept order"%>
```

Comment: Your rails 2 and 3 solution will also work on rails 4.

Comment: yeah, but the Rails 4 solution won't work for Rails 2 and 3 :)

Comment: `f.hidden_field_tag` should be `f.hidden_field`.

Comment: @Pavan right, that was a typo. I had it right in the first place where I showed just the change needed. Thanks :)

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Idk why, but it still doesnt work.  Order_perfomer _id doesnt change.

Comment: How does you params hash look like with this change?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam order_perfomer_id is empty.should i write something to controller also?

Comment: Show your params hash's content please. Also, you are putting `current_user.id` value in the `order_perfomer_id ` hidden field. So, make sure `current_user` is has an id. Also, show your controller's code and tell me what do you want to do with this hidden field in the controller.